# Execute dtsx package on Button click VB fails

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis, dts

I created an Intigration service package named Package.dtsx in visual studio 2017.

when I Execute this package. It run perfect.

But If I have 100's of Packages then I will Execute all separately.

So I want to create a button in VB form so that when I click.
That all packages will run at one go.

but for time being I am trying to Run at least one package using this method.

So I created a button and searched for Code as shown below, but this code is not working.

lblInfo.Text always shows Failure.

Pacakge Properties can be viewed here [Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0EVY.png)

```
Protected Sub Button1_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.ServerClick
    Dim pkgLocation As String
    Dim pkg As New Package
    Dim app As New Application
    Dim pkgResults As DTSExecResult
    Try
        pkgLocation =
          "E:\Integration Services Project3\Integration Services Project3\Package.dtsx"
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, Nothing)
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute()
        lblInfo.Text = pkgResults.ToString()

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblInfo.Text = ex.ToString
    End Try


End Sub
```

Code Copied from here.

[execute SSIS packages from vb.net](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9dbec8ad-442e-43fa-96ed-775b27e61fd9/execute-ssis-packages-from-vbnet?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

and

[How can i execute an SSIS package on a button click from a Visual Studio Web Application (in C#)?](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26527995/How-can-i-execute-an-SSIS-package-on-a-button-click-from-a-Visual-Studio-Web-Application-in-C.html)

Comment: Make pkgLocation an array.  Then use a foreach to enumerate through each package.

Comment: I will use array for all but here the code is not working for at least one. If this code worked for one, then I will use array for all.

Comment: Do you have access to the file/folder?  Is the pathname valid.  Check with Windows Explorer to make sure files are in the location.

Comment: Yes app.LoadPackage successfully Load File and I copied that file path and searched in file explorer. It is opend but not on pkg.Execute().

Comment: Is Package.dtsx property set to read and executable?

Comment: I don't know, from where should I set properties. But I Edited my question above and attached picture of pacakge properties.

Comment: I was thinking the file properties in windows.  Did some searches. Make sure it can run outside c# before trying inside c#
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918760/ssis-package-does-not-run-when-called-from-a-sql-server-agent-job-step
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89aea867-439f-49e1-ae22-e76858d82989/ssis-package-not-executing-from-c?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Yes, as I described that It Run perfect when want to run in VS, as well as I can open file directly. But cannot run through the code provided above.

Comment: Best thing to do is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler. and compare working with non working.